# Need to have separate click event for two different set of checkboxes using jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have two sets of check box. One for categories and one For products.

For **Categories** i have this

```
<div id="category">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cateogry1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cateogry2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cateogry3">
</div>
```

For **Products** i have this

```
<div id="product">
    <input type="checkbox" id="product1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="product2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="product3">
</div>
```

What i did initially was looped through each checkbox and registered a click event for all like this

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function(){
     var localCheckboxId = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
     $(localCheckboxId).click(function() { 
     //did something
     });
});
```

Now i want to separate the click events for both categories and products.

How to do that using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a JQuery selector like this:

```
$("#category input").click(categoryFunction);
```

and like this:

```
$("#product input").click(productFunction);
```

What is happening is that the select first limits the selection to be based on the ID of each `div`. So the `input` part means "only input descendents that belong to the parent ID"

Because you only have checkbox input elements there is no need to specify the type. However, if you do actually use more input types then you can add the extra `:checkbox` part to limit the selector further:

```
$("#category input:checkbox").click(categoryFunction);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/baDRK/1/), it even shows how to get the `id` for the checkbox that is clicked.

Comment: Do you mean `$("#category input:checkbox").each(function(){});`? will this loop all the category check boxes?

Comment: @Coder_sLaY: You don't need to use a loop. JQuery selectors can be used think this and will apply the `click` event to all matched elements. Try it, it will work

Comment: @Coder_sLaY: See my edit, I have posted a JSFiddle link so you can see it working

Answer (score 5):

Use the containing `div` ID:

Products:

```
$("#product input:checkbox").click(...
```

Categories

```
$("#category input:checkbox").click(...
```

Comment: Do you mean `$("#product input:checkbox").each(function(){});`?

Comment: @Coder_sLaY No, you don't need to loop through them. That would be somewhat redundant.

Comment: Nope (you don't need `each`), this method will select every input of type checkbox under product or category and apply the specified relevant click event to them.

Comment: @Coder_sLaY - Perhaps you should read some of the api documentation on selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @TravisJ & MrCode then we dont need `each`. The `click` event will register events for all the respective products and category checkboxes

Comment: @Coder_sLaY `each` is not necessary. If you don't understand it, test it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your loop but add a test on the `input` parent :

```
if($(this).parent().attr('id') === "category") { ... }
else { ... }
```